# How to open a nautilus directory and select a file in it from the command line?

Tags: nautilus, command-line

I know how to open directory, but I do not know how to select a file from the command line.

**Edit:**

I do not know how it works, but when I move any file to a directory and then open the directory that this file is selected.

Comment: Do you mean so a nautilus window opens, with a specific file highlighted and the status bar reading something like '"file.txt" selected (2.6 MB)'?

Comment: Or do you mean you wish to open a file from the command line?

Comment: "Do you mean so a nautilus window opens, with a specific file highlighted [...]" Yes, exactly what I mean

Comment: And what do you want this for ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's actually easier than it seems. What I tried is just this:

```
nautilus <path_to_file>
```

At first, the file doesn't look to be selected, but that's just because the nautilus window isn't active. If you click on it, you'll see that the file name is selected.

Since I guess you want to have that extra visual feedback, I used `xdotool` to make a simple test to select `/var/log/dpkg.log` as follows:

```
nautilus /var/log/dpkg.log && sleep 3 && xdotool search -name log windowactivate
```

What you should see is that nautilus in opened with using `/var/log/` directory and that after three seconds the window is activated (the window name is just `log`) and the file name is highlighted since it's selected.

Note: in this example if sleep is set to a shorter time you might not get the expected result since you need the window to be properly displayed before trying to activate it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's an option to do this.
See:

- `man nautilus`
- `nautilus --help`
- http://live.gnome.org/Nautilus

You *can* open a file as if you had double clicked it in nautilus using the xdg-open command:

```
xdg-open file
```

If you really wanted to have this specific feature, it would require [hacking on the Nautilus code](http://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Development).

Comment: +1 For the information on the `xdg-open` command. I can confirm that there is no way to open nautilus with a specific file selected.

Answer (score 2):

The `gnome-open` command will open a directory with the appropriate application, which in this case is Nautilus:

```
gnome-open PATH
```

This will open the directory `/tmp` using the Nautilus file browser:

```
gnome-open /tmp
```

OR:

```
cd /tmp
gnome-open .
```

I like the `gnome-open` command because you can use this exact same command to open a file with the appropriate application. No need to remember any funny flags. It just works.

`gnome-open file.pdf` will open the PDF in a PDF browser.
`gnome-open file.zip` will open a zip file using the Zip archive viewer.

Answer (score 1):

When you in an xterm, navigating directories on the command line, and then want to pop up a nautilus window for that directory, do this:

```
nautilus --browser .
```